# File stream into Object vector

Tags: c++, class, object, vector

```
class Question
{
public:

    void showQuestion();
    bool checkAnswer(string givenAnswer);
    void showAnswer();
    void markCorrect();

private:

    string level;
    string questionText;
    string answerText;
    bool correct;
};

class Quiz
{
public:

    bool loadQuestions(string dataFileName);
    void dumpQuestions();
    int deliverQuiz();

private:

    vector<Question> questions;

};
```

I have two classes here, Question, and Quiz, I need to read a text file that will have the questions, answers, ect. after reading the file, I will need to store the variables into a vector. I've tried a couple things, created a Question object vector and stored them in that. However, I believe I need to create a Quiz object and store them in the private vector. I am confused how I can go about storing the variables into the Quiz vector object, or what the syntax for that would look like.

In other words, it makes sense to me to create a Question Object vector and store them in that. However it appears i'll need to create a Quiz Object vector, and store the variables in that, im just not sure how to go about that.

Here is an example of my input file format called questions.txt

```
S|1|What is the capital of Italy|Rome
S|1|What is the capital of France|Paris
```

Comment: What does your questions file look like (what's the formatting)? Please provide a brief example of the data. (Put it into your original question, not as a comment)

Comment: https://pastebin.com/LUqQyw9K, - Example of text file questions, and then method of parsing the file.

Comment: Your vector of `Question` objects is already owned by `Quiz` and you named it `questions`.  I don't think you need any other vector here.  It makes sense to use `m` or `m_` or `_` at the beginning of member variable names so you don't get confused when using them in methods.

Answer (score 0):

> However it appears i'll need to create a Quiz Object vector, and store the variables in that

I don't think you need to do that. In your example you have 1 Quiz which owns many Questions.  This makes sense, so I don't think you need to go about creating Quiz object vector.

> I need to read a text file that will have the questions, answers, etc. after reading the file, I will need to store the variables into a vector.

Here is a way to populate your vector of `Question` objects by implementing the `Quiz::loadQuestions()` method you have defined. You will need to provide access to the private members of your `Question` object in order to properly retrieve and populate them (provide accessors and mutators).

```
void Question::setLevel( const int theLevel )
{
   level = theLevel;
}

void Question::setQuestion( const std::string & question )
{
   questionText = question;
}
```

And so on. Once you've done that, and given your input file format, you can populate like this.

```
bool Quiz::loadQuestions( const std::string & fileName )
{
    std::ifstream infile(fileName.c_str());
    if (infile.is_open())
    {
        std::string line;
        while (std::getline(infile, line))
        {
            std::stringstream ss(line);
            std::string token;
            Question temp;

            std::getline(ss, token, '|'); // Type (don't care?)
            std::getline(ss, token, '|'); // Level
            int level = atoi(token.c_str());
            temp.setLevel(level);

            std::getline(ss, token, '|'); // Question
            temp.setQuestion(token);

            std::getline(ss, token, '|'); // Answer
            temp.setAnswer(token);

            // store populated Question object for Quiz
            questions.push_back(temp);
        }
    }
    return (!questions.empty());
}
```

Comment: Ok thank you very much man, making the accessor functions made the difference! This makes a lot more sense.

Comment: @CodeSpyder You’re welcome! Please accept my answer if it worked for you.